# Setting up argparse on Python 3.2

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to set up argparse on my python program but it's not working.
The arguments I'm trying to process are as follows:

Either '--interactive' OR an integer for the first argument, one of these is required

Any one of either '--xml' OR '--html' OR '--text' OR '--console'. Again, it can be any one of these but one of them is required for the second argument

And finally for the third argument, a '--verbose' flag which is optional.

All of these arguments change variables to True, apart from the integer on the first argument.

This is the code I have at the minute:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Historical Event Calculator.',
                             prog='tempus.py')

inputs = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
exports = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

inputs.add_argument('integer', metavar='I', type=float,
               help='percentage to use')

inputs.add_argument('-i','--interactive', dest='bool_interactive', 
               action='store_true', help='enter interactive mode')

exports.add_argument('-x','--xml', dest='bool_xml', action='store_true',
               help='export output as xml')

exports.add_argument('--html', dest='bool_html', action='store_true',
               help='export output as html')

exports.add_argument('-t','--text', dest='bool_text', action='store_true',
               help='export output as plaintext')

exports.add_argument('-c','--console', dest='bool_con', action='store_true',
               help='export output to console')

parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
               help='enter verbose/debug mode', required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

But I have no idea if I'm on the right track with this though, can anyone help? Does this look about right or have I done it completely wrong?

**Edit**

I get this traceback when I pass any flag to it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Callum\Dropbox\Tempus\Feature Tests\argparsetest.py", line 9, in <module>
    help='percentage to use')
  File "C:\Python32\lib\argparse.py", line 1305, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\argparse.py", line 1528, in _add_action
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

Comment: Why don't you simplify and change it so your `--xml`, `--html`, `--text`, `--console` options become a single flag, called `--output=x`, where `x` can be `xml`, `html`, `text`, or `console`, and then set a default for that? Similarly, `--interactive` can be optional, or the `integer` can be optional. Otherwise you're going to have more logic to determine what takes precedence over others.

Comment: Do you have an error? If so, please show a traceback. On a first glance your code seems funtional even, if you should consider birryree's arguments. So if you don't get any errors your post belongs -imho- to code-review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Birryree: How would I go about changing those arguments to that format?

Comment: @DonQuestion: I've added the traceback as an edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error, `ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional`, happened because you are adding `integer` (a positional argument), to a mutually exclusive group. Mutually exclusive groups are only for optional arguments, whereas positional arguments are always required. One solution is to make both `interactive` and `integer` optional arguments, and mutually exclusive them.

I originally missed the fact that you used a `mutually_exclusive_group` on your modes, so that only xml, html, console, or text were specified, but I did change it up if you do like that idea.

This parser would work, it makes your `interactive` and `integer` arguments mutually exclusive, and makes mode a [choice list](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#choices).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='tempus.py')
    ex_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--mode', type=str, choices=['html', 'xml', 'text', 'console'], required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
    ex_group.add_argument('--interactive', action='store_true')
    ex_group.add_argument('--integer', metavar='I', type=float, help='percentage to use')
    return parser

def main():
    aparser = get_parser()
    args = aparser.parse_args()

    print('mode: %s' % args.mode)
    print('integer: %s' % args.integer)
    print('interactive: %s' % args.interactive)
    print('verbose: %s' % args.verbose)

# Only used in Python 2.x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample run:

```
+> python .\tempus.py
usage: tempus.py [-h] --mode {html,xml,text,console} [-v]
                 (--interactive | --integer I)
tempus.py: error: argument --mode is required

+> python .\tempus.py --mode html
usage: tempus.py [-h] --mode {html,xml,text,console} [-v]
                 (--interactive | --integer I)
tempus.py: error: one of the arguments --interactive --integer is required

+> python .\tempus.py --mode html --integer
usage: tempus.py [-h] --mode {html,xml,text,console} [-v]
                 (--interactive | --integer I)
tempus.py: error: argument --integer: expected one argument

+> python .\tempus.py --mode html --integer 12
mode: html
integer: 12.0
interactive: False
verbose: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `integer` to be an optional `positional`

```
inputs.add_argument('integer', nargs='?', metavar='I', type=float, ...)
```

With this, `-i` and `33` would both be accepted by the `inputs` group, `-i 33` would not.